# Determine the list of IR filter's functions/operators in Oracle APEX 19.1

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

Is there a way to hide some Functions/Operators in the Row Filter of APEX 19.1's Interactive Report? Some end-users get confused with as many functions/operators that they do not used.

Thanks for any considerations.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While APEX doesn't support this out of the box, it is doable with JavaScript. Every time the filter dialog is displayed, content is brought from the server to the client and injected into the DOM. You just need to modify the content before the user can see it. One way to achieve this is by using the MutationObserver interface: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Here are some steps you could follow to do it (tested in APEX 19.2):

1. Go to the Interactive Report and set the **Static ID** to **my-irr**.
2. Go to the page level attributes and add the following code to the **Function and Global Variable Declaration** field:

   ```
   function removeIRFilterOperators() {
     var irRegId = 'my-irr';
     var filterOperatorsToRemove = ['!=', 'ABS'];
     var observer;

     function detectFilterDialog(mutationsList) {
       for (var mIdx = 0; mIdx < mutationsList.length; mIdx++) {
         if (mutationsList[mIdx].addedNodes.length && 
           mutationsList[mIdx].addedNodes[0].classList &&
           mutationsList[mIdx].addedNodes[0].classList.contains('a-IRR-dialog--filter')) {
             removeOperators();
         }
       }
     }

     function removeOperators() {
       var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('#' + irRegId + '_row_filter_operators a');

       for (var aIdx = 0; aIdx < anchors.length; aIdx++) {
         if (filterOperatorsToRemove.includes(anchors[aIdx].textContent)) {
           anchors[aIdx].parentElement.parentElement.removeChild(anchors[aIdx].parentElement);
         }
       }
     }

     observer = new MutationObserver(detectFilterDialog);

     observer.observe(
       document, 
       {
         attributes: false,
         childList: true, 
         subtree: true
       }
     );
   }

   removeIRFilterOperators();
   ```

The MutationObverver uses the `detectFilterDialog` function to detect when the filter dialog is added to the DOM. When that happens, the `removeOperators` function removes the specified options from the operator's list. All you need to do is update the `filterOperatorsToRemove` array to include the list of operators you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the "Actions" menu, then yes - go to IR's attributes and enable/disable any option you want:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Littlefoot, but I am talking about functions/operators such as ABS, ADD_MONTH, BETWEEN, CEIL, etc...The list that is provided inside the Row Filter in the Filter under Actions menu. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Aha, I see. I wouldn't know whether it is possible or not. If I had to guess, I'd say **not**.